# Laravel: Nested loop html option and increasing the indent (prefix)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I want to display indented subcategories in the html option tag. I created a recursive iteration in a separate file that I import in a foreach statement.
With the first subcategories, I get a prefix of one space and when it starts to load deeper levels, the indent is the same and should be increased by one more.

How can i increase the indented (prefix) for each level that is deeper?

**I expect it to be like this:**

```
Root
  Child
    Sub child 1
    Sub child 2
      Sub sub child
```

**My real exmple when code is excuted is like this:**

```
Root
  Child
  Sub child 1
  Sub child 2
  Sub sub child
```

*(no prefix spaces in Sub childrens)*

**Controller**

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = BlogCategory::where('parent_id', '')->get();

    return view('ecommerce::admin.post.create', [
        'categories' => $categories
    ]);
}
```

**form.blade.php**

```
<select name="public" id="page_category_field" class="custom-select {{ $errors->has('status') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}}">
        @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>

            @if(count($category->childrens) > 0)
                @include('ecommerce::admin.post.loop.nested_category_html_select', ['childrens' => $category->childrens])
            @endif
        @endforeach
</select>
```

**nested_category_html_select.blade.php**

```
@foreach($childrens as $child)
    <option value="{{ $child->id }}">&nbsp; {{ $child->name }}</option>

    @if(count($child->childrens) > 0)
        @include('ecommerce::admin.post.loop.nested_category_html_select', ['childrens' => $child->childrens])
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Here is problem in `&nbsp`:

```
<option value="{{ $child->id }}">&nbsp; {{ $child->name }}</option>
```

How to add more spaces for each new level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be very basic (not the best solution), but one simple and quick solution would be for you to pass another variable specifying the level of indentation you want:

##### `nested_category_html_select.blade.php`

```html
@foreach($childrens as $child)
    <option value="{{ $child->id }}">
        @foreach(range(1, $level ?? 1) as $l)
            &nbsp;
        @endforeach
        {{ $child->name }}
    </option>

    @if(count($child->childrens) > 0)
        @include('ecommerce::admin.post.loop.nested_category_html_select', ['childrens' => $child->children's, 'level' => $level + 1])
    @endif
@endforeach
```

The code may not exactly work as I did not use blade in a long time, but the idea would be for you to add spaces based on the level you are currently at.

One more thing you would need to modify is having `$level` available on the blade file, so if no one inputs something, it has `$level = 1`, and then you increment by 1.

Comment: It's a bit dirty but it does the job :D

Comment: @Ivan yeah, I usually do not do this, but as I said in the answer at the beginning, quick and basic!

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code using the `str_repeat` function to handle the indentation.

```
@foreach($childrens as $child)
    <option value="{{ $child->id }}">
        {{ str_repeat('&nbsp;', $level ?? 1) }}{{ $child->name }}
    </option>

    @if(count($child->childrens) > 0)
        @include('ecommerce::admin.post.loop.nested_category_html_select', ['childrens' => $child->childrens, 'level' => $level + 1])
    @endif
@endforeach
```

This uses `str_repeat('&nbsp;', $level ?? 1)` to repeat the non-breaking space character `(&nbsp;)` based on the level, achieving the same indentation effect as your original code.